# Parse block content as html from module Drupal

Tags: php, html, drupal, drupal-7

I'am working on a module Drupal that needs an attribute value from another module, to get the block I found this :

```
$block = module_invoke('mymodule', 'block_view', 'myblock');
```

so I want to parse `$block['content']` as html text and find my needed attribute.
Is there a way to do that by simple method like `find()` or `getElementById()`

Any idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code as shown below:

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($block['content']);
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
        # Show the <a href>
        echo $link->getAttribute('href');
        echo "<br />";
}
```

Reference: http://htmlparsing.com/php.html

Comment: thank you @Vishal for your time, I used http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm  and it works :  `$html_block=str_get_html($block['content']);
    $Selected=$html_block->find('li[selected=Yes]');
    $id_selected=$Selected->itemDBId;`